# Any cordova plugin to add WebAuthn API to Android WebView?

Tags: android-webview, cordova-plugins, webauthn, fido

We've developed a cordova app that shows one of our websites (which is also accessible using a web browser).
Recently, FIDO2 authentication using WebAuthn has been added to that website. This works fine in the tested browsers (Chrome and Firefox), but not in our cordova application, as it uses Android WebView, which doesn't implement the WebAuthn API.

Does anybody know if there is any cordova plugin to add this API to Android WebView?
Is there any website with information about the Android WebView roadmap (bugs that will be fixed in next release, new features that will be added, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that Android WebView doesn't support WebAuthn in Android 13. We hope to address that in the Android 14 timeframe but, for now, you have to inject Javascript hooks and use a Javascript bridge to implement it. It's certainly possible to do but I'm not aware of any packaged solutions that do it.